# Emacs: how to reassign C-x 5 2 (switch frame) to C-` in the .emacs profile

Tags: macos, mac, emacs

To make emacs more osx-esque, I'd ike to reassign C-x 5 2 (switch frames) to C-` (I have command mapped to C-). What should I add to my .emacs profile to do this?

**EDIT**
Sorry - meant C-x 5 o (switch frames), but the answers are still relevant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do C-h k followed by C-x 5 2 to get the name of the function that You want to reassign.
Do M-x global-set-key followed by C-backtick and then type the name of the function.
Do C-x ESC ESC and copy the lisp expression to your .emacs

Answer (score 1):

Put this line of Elisp code into your .emacs startup file:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-`") 'make-frame-command)
```

Beware, that C-` is not a real character, so this will only work when Emacs is using its graphical interface.

Comment: I found that I can get at ` using the following: (global-set-key (quote [67108960]) (quote other-frame))

Comment: While that syntax works, it's not very maintainable.  That's why the kbd function was created.  In fact, if you evaluate (kbd "C-\`"), the value is [67108960].  That big number is just Emacs' internal character code for C-`.