# Mapping Command-<left> in Emacs to move cursor to beginning of line

Tags: macos, emacs

Anyone knows what needs changing in OSX .emacs to get Command-left to act as C-a and move the cursor to beginning of line? The same for Command-right, I'd like to map it to move the cursor to end of line.

Thx!

Comment: http://www.dansanderson.com/blog/2007/10/ctrlleft-and-ctrlright-for-mac.html

Comment: Thx Sonia, but I already knew how to do that. What I was asking here is how to get to the beginning or end of line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<s-right>") 'move-end-of-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "<s-left>") 'move-beginning-of-line)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a generic method see https://superuser.com/a/418251/130126

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand that method.

Comment: Argh!! I tried to link to my answer, but for some reason you have to scoll up a bit. <br>

Comment: Do C-h k followed by C-x 5 2 to get the name of the function that you want to reassign. Do M-x global-set-key <return>, press the key you want to assign it to, and then type the name of the function. Do C-x ESC ESC and copy the lisp expression to your .emacs